# Capture the column index in R or excel for a series of data for a condition

Tags: r, excel

I would like to capture the index value for any value less than 500 for a series of data.

Below is how my data looks like

```
Category,Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4,Price5,Price6
Product1,967,855,929,811,501,387
Product2,526,809,723,304,315,671
Product3,412,133,369,930,400,337
Product4,709,241,625,822,967,952
Product5,395,506,110,280,829,817
Product6,803,618,794,214,605,788
```

For example, in the first row, Price6 is the first element for the series between Price1 to Price6, where value is less than 500, hence in the output "First" has 6.
Similarly, for second row, Price4 has less than 500, and next Price5 has less than 500, hence the value for First and Second are 4,5 respectively for the series of data between price1 and Price6.

When nothing is capture in the logic, i want to place a "-" for the same.

Below is the output i am looking for.

```
Category,Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4,Price5,Price6,First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth,Sixth
Product1,967,855,929,811,501,387,6,-,-,-,-,-
Product2,526,809,723,304,315,671,4,5,-,-,-,-
Product3,412,133,369,930,400,337,1,2,3,5,6,-
Product4,709,241,625,822,967,952,2,-,-,-,-,-
Product5,395,506,110,280,829,817,1,3,4,-,-,-
Product6,803,618,794,214,605,788,4,-,-,-,-,-
```

Not sure how to do the same in R or excel.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example data

Comment: The desired output is really clunky. Maybe consider flags instead, e.g. if your data frame is called `data`, then something like `apply(data,1,function(x) ifelse(x<500,1,0))`?

Comment: tried it.. its simply allocating standard values, rather than giving index values...

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
dt[, when := melt(dt, id.vars = "Category")[, toString(which(value < 500)), Category][, V1]]
cbind(dt, dt[, tstrsplit(when, ", ", fill = "-")])
```

Gives

```
   Category Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4 Price5 Price6          when V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1: Product1    967    855    929    811    501    387             6  6  -  -  -  -
2: Product2    526    809    723    304    315    671          4, 5  4  5  -  -  -
3: Product3    412    133    369    930    400    337 1, 2, 3, 5, 6  1  2  3  5  6
4: Product4    709    241    625    822    967    952             2  2  -  -  -  -
5: Product5    395    506    110    280    829    817       1, 3, 4  1  3  4  -  -
6: Product6    803    618    794    214    605    788             4  4  -  -  -  -
```

Now you just need to replace the names V1-V5 and drop column when.

Data:

```
dt <- fread("Category,Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4,Price5,Price6
Product1,967,855,929,811,501,387
Product2,526,809,723,304,315,671
Product3,412,133,369,930,400,337
Product4,709,241,625,822,967,952
Product5,395,506,110,280,829,817
Product6,803,618,794,214,605,788")
```

Comment: I am getting "Error in ':=( when, melt(dt, id.vars.................." Check that is.data.table(DT)= TRUE, otherwise , := and ':='(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways.. see help(":=")

Comment: do `setDT(dt)` first And make sure to install and load data.table first.

Answer (score 1):

One can try `apply` and `tidyr::separate` based solution as:

```
# First merge the data after moving values < 500 in left. 
# The empty places should be filled with `-`
df$DesiredData <- apply(df[2:7],1,function(x){
  value <- x[x<500]
  paste0(c(value,rep("-",length(x)-length(value))),collapse = ",")
})

library(tidyverse)

# Now use `separate` function to split column in 6 desired columns
df %>% separate("DesiredData",
          c("First","Second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth"), sep = ",")

#   Category Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4 Price5 Price6 First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth
# 1 Product1    967    855    929    811    501    387   387      -     -      -     -     -
# 2 Product2    526    809    723    304    315    671   304    315     -      -     -     -
# 3 Product3    412    133    369    930    400    337   412    133   369    400   337     -
# 4 Product4    709    241    625    822    967    952   241      -     -      -     -     -
# 5 Product5    395    506    110    280    829    817   395    110   280      -     -     -
# 6 Product6    803    618    794    214    605    788   214      -     -      -     -     -
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
Category,Price1,Price2,Price3,Price4,Price5,Price6
Product1,967,855,929,811,501,387
Product2,526,809,723,304,315,671
Product3,412,133,369,930,400,337
Product4,709,241,625,822,967,952
Product5,395,506,110,280,829,817
Product6,803,618,794,214,605,788",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep=",")
```